# how to detect if scroll is happening within certain element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll

I wanted to detect if the pointer scroll is happening within a certain element and then do certain actions. I've tried this code but it seems to not working:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(".class-name").scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           console.log("scroll down");
       } else {
          console.log("scroll up");
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: it is unclear what you are actually trying to do. So you are detecting scrolling in that element?

Comment: I'd like to execute certain code when I do a scroll down and the pointer is within a div with class name = .class-name

Comment: So your code is saying when I scroll in this element I am checking to see if the scrolltop is moving up or down.....  Issue with this is if you have more than one element, you are sharing the same global variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:

`scrollTop` gives you the current position of the scroll bar of the **element** not of the page.
So if he hasn't scroll bar it will be 0.:

> or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.

and the same for `.scroll()` if the element hasn't scroll bar it will never occur.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(".class-name").scroll(function(event){
       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           console.log("scroll down");
       } else {
          console.log("scroll up");
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

```css
.class-name{
width:100px;
height:200px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-name">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </div>
```

Comment: I think my problem was that the div item has not overflow. at the moment I checked the scroll on windows and a boolen value if the pointer is on that div. Thanks for your answer anyway